# Is there a way to make a legend when symbology shows "Embedded symbols"?

Tags: qgis

I have a MapInfo file that opens correctly in QGIS, which even displays original polygon colors from the original file.
When I open "Layer Properties - Symbology" dialogue, it says "Embedded symbols" are displayed and some random single color as the symbol color is displayed. I don't see a way to make a legend starting from this.
I'd hate to mess up the colors as they're exactly what I need, and I would also hate to have to go through the whole "Categorized" symbolization process in order to have a proper legend.
So, is there an easy way to make a legend that would honor the colors already defined in this MapInfo file?

I don't even know where to start, except to do it all over again.